# Hyperlink formula field not visible in List view for lightning

Tags: lightning, formula, hyperlink

I have one hyperlink formula field-

`HYPERLINK("/apex/Submit_Forecast?id=" +Id & "/view", Name )`

I added this field in `All` list view of object. It is working fine in salesforce classic but failing in Lightning. What can we do in such case?

Comment: tried your way but it didn't help.

Comment: is there any other way to show this field in list view?

Comment: my hyperlink is working fine. the problem is when i am adding it in list view and seeing it in lightning i am getting value as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Lightning as well as Classic view of Salesforce. 
Here is the code: `HYPERLINK("/apex/Submit_Forecast?id="& Id&"&view="& Name,Name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a recent update has broken the original links. Mine have stopped working in Lightning as well. They're now being labeled as 'undefined' although it works in Classic.